# Flask Application Context: app.app_context().push() works but can't get "with app.app_context()" block to work

Tags: flask

I am new to flask, having written just one fairly simple web app -- no db, just a front-end for a flight search API. It all works fine, but to improve my skills I am trying to re-factor my code with an application factory and blueprints. Got it to work with `push()` but cannot get `with` block to work.

```
fly_app/__init.py__
```

My original code:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

if not app.debug:
    ...

from fly_app import routes, errors  # noqa
```

I imported the app to other modules as needed.

Now that file has been refactored to this and seems to work:

```
from flask import Flask
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import os


def create_app():
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY=os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'nice-try')
    )
    app.app_context().push()

    if not app.debug and not app.testing:
        ...

    from . import routes
    app.register_blueprint(routes.bp)

    return app
```

I need the app_context so I can use current_app.static_folder and current_app.logger.exception() in other modules. I have read that using a `with` block, e.g.,

```
with app.app_context():
    init_db()
```

is preferred to

```
app.app_context().push()
```

From Flask documentation: "Use app_context() in a with block, and everything that runs in the block will have access to current_app."

My questions:

1. How is the `with` block different or better than using
   `app.app_context().push()`?
2. Does using `push()` amount to making `app` a global variable as in my original code, thus accomplishing nothing?
3. I cannot figure out how to get `with` block to work without raising "RuntimeError: Working outside of application context." I have tried the `with` block including:

   - `app.static_folder`
   - `current_app` (after importing it) or `current_app.[attr]`
   - specific module.methods() or attributes that use current_app

For example, I wrote two custom validators -- code_check and currency_check -- to use with classes derived from  `flask_wtf.FlaskForm` in `forms.py` module. These take `form` and `field` positional args that I cannot put in the with block because they are undefined.

Being a relative newbie, I am obviously not understanding how the application context works, despite reading docs and searching internet.

Answer (score 5):

Piecing together code from multiples sources when new at Flask is a recipe for frustration. I see the direction you're headed, and strongly recommend you to read through Miguel Grinberg's [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world). It lays out a path that can give you a better sense for how Flask works.

(Hint: There's no need for `app.app_context().push()` in `create_app()`)

Comment: Thanks. I first learned Flask with Miguel's tutorial but never finished it because I had all the pieces I needed to get my simple flight search application working.  Now as a learning experience I am trying to re-factor my code using an application factory. I  went through Flask's [tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/). I also went back to Miguel's tutorial, Part XV, A Better Application Structure. He creates instance of extensions and in his app factory he calls instance.init_app(app). That does not seem relevant to my case. If I don't push() I get context error.

Comment: You'll need the `app.app_context().push()` (or `with app.app_context(): ...` whenever you need something that's been configured along with the app (like the `db`, which depends on `db.init_app(app)` to configure it), or you need to do something that Flask expects a request context for. Doing it in `create_app()` leaves the Flask machinery in an unusual state that might cause you mysterious problems elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks again. I think you are saying it's better to _not_ manually push an application context if avoidable. From Flask docs: "Flask automatically pushes an application context when handling a request." But I felt I needed to push application context for a simple task, defining a path to JSON files outside of a request, eg:

`code_dir = os.path.join(current_app.static_folder, 'JSON/optd_codes.json')`

So I found way around that, by setting: 
`bp = Blueprint('routes', __name__, static_folder='./static')` 
and 
`code_dir = os.path.join(bp.static_folder, 'JSON/optd_codes.json')`

Better?

Comment: That looks better. You'll still need the app context to things outside of a request context (e.g., for unit tests and cli stuff), but getting (pushing) that context as close to the thing you need it for will save you debugging grief.

Comment: Hi you have mentioned that "Doing it in create_app() leaves the Flask machinery in an unusual state that might cause you mysterious problems elsewhere". Say I have package with factory create_app in init file. And in factory I want to import views.py (views.py makes use of @current_app.routes to configure the routes), then I must push the app.context to import the views.py file. Otherwise it will give error that I am working outside app context. Is there any alternative for this? I know blueprint is an alternative, but if my app has obly 4 routes then I wouldn't want to make blueprint.

Comment: "but if my app has obly 4 routes then I wouldn't want to make blueprint." Why not? They're a very lightweight mechanism, intended for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

I think I can adequately answer my 3-part question above. First, the 3rd part -- what to put in the `with` block. That answer is embarrassingly simple:

```
fly_app.__init__.py

from flask import Flask
...


def create_app():
    ...

    with app.app_context():
        from . import routes
        app.register_blueprint(routes.bp)

    return app
```

All I needed to do was put the blueprint registration in the `with` block. Everything seemed to work after that. (Ultimately, I decided *not* to go in that direction (explained below).

Regarding parts 1 & 2 -- how is `with` block different than `push()`, and does `push()` confer global access to the application context? I am not certain of these answers, but playing around in the interpreter gave me some insights. When I used `app.app_context().push()` in my `create_app()` function:

```
>>> import fly_app
>>> from flask import current_app
>>> current_app
<LocalProxy unbound>
>>> fly_app.create_app()
<Flask 'fly_app'>
>>> current_app
<Flask 'fly_app'>
>>> current_app.static_folder
'/Users/Steve/.../fly_app/static'
```

`current_app` and its attributes are immediately available. But if I used the `with` block to import and register my `routes.bp` I got different results. `current_app` is not openly bound or available:

```
>>> import fly_app
>>> from flask import current_app
>>> current_app
<LocalProxy unbound>
>>> fly_app.create_app()
<Flask 'fly_app'>
>>> current_app
<LocalProxy unbound>
>>> fly_app.routes.current_app.static_folder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

But `code_dir = os.path.join(current_app.static_folder, 'JSON/optd_codes.json')` still works:

```
>>> fly_app.routes.code_dir
'/Users/Steve/Documents/flask_requests_env/dragonfly/fly_app/static/JSON/optd_codes.json'
```

So my inference from these observations is that `app.app_context().push()` does seem to make the application context globally available, but using a `with` block does not. Or in my non-CS interpretation, the application context is available, but more narrowly, i.e., only to specified parts of my application.

Ultimately, thanks to guidance from David W. Smith (see his answer and my conversation with him in comments), I decided that needing a path to the static folder was not a good reason to manually push an application context. I used the `static_folder` keyword argument for my `Blueprint` and replaced `current_app.static_folder` with `bp.static_folder`. No need for a manual push.